# Watch windows not updating correctly when debugging C++/CLI 2D arrays

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, debugging, watch-window

I'm debugging a C++/CLI assembly.  In the assembly, I have a 2D managed array declared like this:

```
array<char, 2> ^classifications;
```

I have four variables I'm using to access positions in the array:

```
int x, y, dx, dy;
```

In the Watch window, this expression works:

```
classifications[y, x]
```

However, this expression does not update when the values of dx and dy change:

```
classifications[y + dy, x + dx]
```

Does anyone know why it's not working?  To be clear, this is a debug build and I've tried a clean rebuild with no success.